# LaTex table over the width of the page

Tags: latex, tabular

I am trying to replicate this table in Latex.

[image: the table I want to replicate]

However my tables always come out like this:

[image: my result]

My code:

```latex
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \textbf{SQL} & \textbf{MONGODB} \\
    Database & Database \\
    Table & Collection \\
    Row & Document \\
    Column & Field \\
    &  \\
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Can you make a *compilable* [mre], e.g. starting with the documentclass until `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 2):

The image you have added contains 6 different tables. In the following MWE, I have reproduced (approximate) the 1st table. You may reproduce all the tables in the same approach.

- The package `tabularx` is necessary for the `X` type column. You can read [this Wikibook section](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabularx_package) for more information.
- `booktabs` package is used for better horizontal lines. In the [package documentation](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf), you will find more about formal tables.
- The package `caption` provides more control on placing captions in floating environments.
- `geometry` package can be used to change page dimensions.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Terminologies in SQL and ...}
    \label{tab:my_label}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
    \toprule
    \textbf{SQL} & \textbf{MONGODB} \\
    \midrule
    Database & Database \\
    Table & Collection \\
    Row & Document \\
    Column & Field \\
    Primary key (specify any unique column or column combination as primary key) & Primary key (the primary key is automatically set to the \_id field in MongoDB)\\
    blah blah & blah blah \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the parameters of the table, for example, use: `p`, `m`, etc. to specify the width of the table. Or use a relatively new table macro package (`tabularray`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Terminologies in SQL and ...}
    \begin{tabular}{m{6cm}m{6cm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{SQL} & \textbf{MONGODB} \\
    \midrule
    Database & Database \\
    Table & Collection \\
    Row & Document \\
    Column & Field \\
    Primary key (specify any unique column or column combination as primary key) & Primary key (the primary key is automatically set to the \_id field in MongoDB)\\
    blah blah & blah blah \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{tblr}{XX}
\toprule
    \textbf{SQL} & \textbf{MONGODB} \\
\midrule
    Database & Database \\
    Table & Collection \\
    Row & Document \\
    Column & Field \\
    Primary key (specify any unique column or column combination as primary key) & Primary key (the primary key is automatically set to the \_id field in MongoDB)\\
    blah blah & blah blah \\
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

A sketch of my suggestion:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

\begin{table}[!ht]
\sffamily
\caption{Terminologies in SQL \& corresponding in MongoDB}
\label{tab:my_label}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{p{0.5\textwidth}}}
\toprule
\textbf{SQL} & \textbf{MongoDB}\\
\midrule
Database & Database\\
\dots & \dots \\
Primary key (specify any unique column or column combinations as primary key) & Primary key (the primary key is\par auto\-matically set to the \_id field\par in MongoDB)\\
\dots & \dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

I added the command `\sffamily` to output the individual table in sans-serif-font.

The command `\par` is to manually add a line-break within a column of type `p` (*paragraph*).

If your table exceeds the height of the page instead, you can check the package [`longtable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable), that you can anyway combine with [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).